# Раскрывающаяся книга

Tags: jquery, анимация, html, css, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью css и js можно сделать анимацию раскрывающийся книги таким образом:

[image]

Comment: Здесь посмотрите http://www.script-tutorials.com/3d-css3-book-generator-with-jquery/

Comment: http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/11/trapeze.html

Comment: http://stekolschikov.tk/demo/2/%D0%A2%D0%972/1/

Answer (score 1):

Пример использования: [клик](http://bro.phpdesigner.in.ua/bio/)

[turn.js](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/blob/master/demos/magazine/index.html)

Comment: Прикольно, но не то что требуется